# having trouble with getting google script to move file into newly created folder within same script

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

as stated above

I'm trying to create a script that will do the following:

create a folder based on the value of F8 - Done and working
place a hyperlink for the folder in a separate sheet - done and working
create a copy of the sheet that the script is running on and place it in the folder it created - sending me insane

below is my code and any help would be awesome

```
function foler() {

 const parent = DriveApp.getFolderById("1hEjlSMhyvKCuL5Pot-FF80-37IKjcIjd");
 var vs = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
 var value = vs.getRange("F8").getValue();
 var sss = SpreadsheetApp.openById('1Gu8NjKdqfrxtxdXJX00UzexgCuVB75QaKdGqjix2yUY');
 const sh = sss.getSheetByName('Estimator Quoting');
 var aValues = sh.getRange("A1:A").getValues();
 var aLast = aValues.filter(String).length;
 // Consider checking if this r & c has a formula in the equal size array from getFormulas()
 if(value) {
   var newLink = getLinkFrFolderName_(parent, value);
   // Use the current array index to write this formula in only the correct cell.
   sh.getRange('A' + (aLast + 1)).setFormula("HYPERLINK(\"" + newLink + "\", \"" + value + "\")"
   );

 var file = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getId();
 var vs = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
 var valu = vs.getRange("F8").getValue();
 var folders = DriveApp.getFoldersByName(valu);
 var destFolder = DriveApp.getFolderById(folders); 
 DriveApp.getFileById(file).makeCopy("Frame, Truss and Take off", destFolder); 
}
```

and this is the code that creates the folder

```
function getLinkFrFolderName_(root, name) {
  var folder;
  const search = root.getFoldersByName(name);
  if (search.hasNext()) {
    folder = search.next();
    if (search.hasNext())
      console.warn("Multiple folders named '" + name + "' in root folder '" + root.getName() + "'");
  }
  else {
  folder = root.createFolder(name);
  ["Quotes", "Plans"].forEach(function(e) {
    folder.createFolder(e);
  });
    return folder.getUrl();
}
```

Comment: I have to apologize for my poor English skill. Unfortunately, I cannot understand the current issue of your script. Can I ask you about the detail of your current issue?

Comment: In  these two lines folders is an iterator not an id. `var folders = DriveApp.getFoldersByName(valu);
 var destFolder = DriveApp.getFolderById(folders); `

Comment: `var valu = vs.getRange("F8").getValue();` what is the value of `valu`?

Comment: Do you get any specific error message or what is the behavior when using that script?

Comment: the value of valu is what the folder is label based on a cell in the sheet

Comment: Exception: Unexpected error while getting the method or property getFolderById on object DriveApp.
foler @ Code.gs:53

Comment: the id of the folder is unknown until the process has started

Answer (score 1):

i figured it out, see below for the fixed code

`````
function folder() {

  const parent = DriveApp.getFolderById("xxxxxx");
  var vs = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
  var value = vs.getRange("F8").getValue();
  var sss = SpreadsheetApp.openById('xxxxxx');
  const sh = sss.getSheetByName('Estimator Quoting');
  var aValues = sh.getRange("A1:A").getValues();
  var aLast = aValues.filter(String).length;
  // Consider checking if this r & c has a formula in the equal size array from getFormulas()
  if(value) {
    var newLink = getLinkFrFolderName_(parent, value);
    // Use the current array index to write this formula in only the correct cell.
    sh.getRange('A' + (aLast + 1)).setFormula("HYPERLINK(\"" + newLink + "\", \"" + value + "\")"
    );
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var TestRange = sheet.getRangeByName('Sheet1'); 
  Logger.log(TestRange); 
  var id = DriveApp.getFoldersByName(value).next().getId();
  var destFolder = DriveApp.getFolderById(id);
  DriveApp.getFileById(sheet.getId()).makeCopy("Frame and Truss", destFolder); 
    };
}
````
`````